# (isset $_POST['submit']) condition is always false

Tags: php, html, post

I wrote the following code in a page named : addSection.php

```html
<from class="mainSettingsForm add" action="" method="post">
    <h1>Add new section</h1>
    <p>
        <label>new section</label>
        <input type="text" name="section_name" placeholder="section title">
        <label>section status</label>
        <select name="sectionStatus">
            <option value="active">active</option>
            <option value="disActive">disActive</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>section location</label>
        <select name="sectionLocation">
            <option value="Side">Side</option>
            <option value="Body">Body</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <label>section description</label>
    <textarea name="sectionDesc" placeholder="Section description"></textarea>
    <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">


</from>
```

and the following code in a page named : Sections.php

```html
<h2><a href="?page=sections&action=add">Add new section</a></h2>
<?php

if ($_POST OR @$_GET['action'])
{
    if (isset($_GET['action']) AND $_GET['action']=="add")
    {
        include 'views/addSection.php';
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])&&$_POST['submit']=="Add")
            echo 'ok';

    }

}
else
{
   include 'views/sections.php';
}

?>
```

this statement
if (isset($_POST['submit'])&&$_POST['submit']=="Add")
            echo 'ok';
is never be executed because it always gives false value , how can make isset($POST['submit']) statement gives true value to execute the condition ?

Comment: Your tags are wrong. It's `<form>...</form>` (not `<from>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement can never be true because the second IF statement is only for `$_GET` variables and then you try to access `$_POST` inside it. You can't have a GET and a POST at the same time.

You also have a few typos - `$_GET['action']` will be "Add" not "add" and you have `<from>` instead of `<form>` in your HTML.

```
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) && $_POST['submit'] == "Add" ){
    echo "this is a POST and submit is add";
} elseif ( isset( $_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "Add" ){
    echo "this is a GET and submit is add";
} else {
    include 'views/sections.php';
}
```

Comment: I took the IF statement outside of IF statement of Get , but i got the same result

Comment: thank you very much, i just edited from to form and it worked,,, thank you very much sir

Answer (score 0):

Please try my code. This will help you to understand what are you passing. I also fix the form tag - as  @Hobo Sapiens suggested.

```
<?php print_r($_REQUEST);?>
<form class="mainSettingsForm add" action="" method="post">
    <h1>Add new section</h1>
    <p>
        <label>new section</label>
        <input type="text" name="section_name" placeholder="section title">
        <label>section status</label>
        <select name="sectionStatus">
            <option value="active">active</option>
            <option value="disActive">disActive</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>section location</label>
        <select name="sectionLocation">
            <option value="Side">Side</option>
            <option value="Body">Body</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <label>section description</label>
    <textarea name="sectionDesc" placeholder="Section description"></textarea>
    <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">


</form>
```

Comment: The PHP is also invalid in the example.

Comment: Agreed.  I am not giving him just a fish, I am teaching him how to fish (troubleshoot/debug). :)

Comment: you are welcome @WessamAlkumait. Also, I recommend you xdebug and breakpoints :)